# Unable to lock Central Inventory. OPatch will attempt to re-lock

Tags: oracle, oracle-fusion-middleware

Am installing an `patch` for `Fusion Middleware` in `windows7` machine. 
While applying the `patch`(command:  opatch apply) getting error as follows:

```
Unable to lock Central Inventory. OPatch will attempt to re-lock.
```

Kindly help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Check if you are running cmd as administrator. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Sadly, most people don't have admin right on their work computer

Answer (score 2):

Found Solution:

1. Remove the "locks" folder inside Oracle_Home/inventory.
2. Remove the ".patch_storage" folder inside the Oracle_Home.

Make sure, `JDK` & `PATH`(*set path=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\OPatch;%path%*) to be set.

Then execute the command **opatch apply**

Enjoy Patching.